# Как сделать вызов всех функций через общий интерфейс?

Tags: c, метапрограммирование

В общем  имеем С89, необходимо что бы каждый вызов функции происходил через некоторый интерфейс (другую функцию)

```
void Caller(callable_function_type F, ...){
    F(...);
}
```

При этом F() должна быть любой возможной функцией, а еще лучше функцией определенного типа, при этом нужно как то сохранять все параметры исходной функции и передавать их в колер, кроме того колер должен вроде как выполняться автоматически.

Рассматриваются варианты : имитация декораторов как в питон макросами, модификация prologue, epilog.

Не рассматривается: добавление в тело нужных функций макроса.

Comment: если не боятся и научиться параметры правильно в стек/регистры запихать (а оно различно для 32/64 битной платформы, да ещё и для различных компиляторов может быть разным), то никаких проблем (ну разве что нужно будет верифицировать кол-во параметров, а то и стек можно сорвать).

Comment: Если я правильно вас понял, то ваш ответ не имеет смысла. Так как мне придется писать обертку (да еще и на асм) для каждой функции, что как вы поняли не требуется. Конечно можно модифицировать preamble генерируемый компилятором (ну т.е заставить генерировать его другой preamble), но я не знаю как.

Comment: Вы меня неправильно поняли. Вам нужно будет писать обертку под различные виды компиляторов/платформ. В кратце это будет выглядеть так - функция смотрит, сколько параметров прибежало, добавляет их в стек в правильном порядке, вызывает функцию. Но как тут без ассемблера обойтись - я так сходу и не скажу.

Comment: Проблема не в том как обойтись без ассемблера, а как заставить вызываться мой код. ибо вызов функции на ассемблере это просто call far __fName. Т.е алгоритм компилятора который создает вызывающую функцию такой смотрим че там пользователь понаписал в прототипе -> создаем преамбулу -> call far __fName -> создаем эпилог, опять же по том че там пользователь написал в return type.

Comment: а где пользователь написал прототип ?

Comment: Перечитал вопрос. Видимо придется цеплятся отладчиком (например, gdb) и делать "неинтерактивную отладку". Но теперь возникает вопрос - а какой смысл в этом "колере".

Comment: Протоип ну в h файле. Я так то не пишу на asm, я пишу на C, но я готов написать ассемблерную вставку которая будет прологом функции. смысл в том, что например мы можем в рантайме иметь call tree. Каждый вызов будет проходить через интерфейс с возможностью отмены и модификации вызываемой рутины.

Answer (score 1):

Буду сюда добавлять инфу по тому что узнал.
**GCC** рантайм содержит такие функции

```
void __cyg_profile_func_enter(void *this_fn, void *call_site);
void __cyg_profile_func_exit(void *this_fn, void *call_site);
```

Задают функции которые волняются при вызове и выходе из любой функции.

**OpenWatcom** умеет даже менять эпилог/пролог

```
-ee           call epilogue hook routine
-ep[=<num>]   call prologue hook routine with <num> stack bytes available
```

Активация этих флагов приведет к тому что при вызове/возврате из функции будут выполняться хуки __EPI и __PRO.

Но у меня BCC 3.1 и походу он умеет только генерировать на выбор стандартные пролог и эпилог под компилируемую платформу.

Почерпнуто отсюда:
[Is there a compiler feature to inject custom function entry and exit code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472769/is-there-a-compiler-feature-to-inject-custom-function-entry-and-exit-code)

Answer (score 0):

Использовать указатели на функции. передавать пустой указатель и используя параметры преобразовывать к нужной функции.

```
void Caller(void * fun,int flag, ...)
{
  int flag;  
  int (*f1)(int) = (int(*)(int))fun;
  int (*f2)(int,int) = (int(*)(int,int))fun;
  va_list argptr;
  va_start(argptr,flag);
  ....
  switch(flag)
    case 1:
      *f1(v1);
       break;
    case 2:
       *f2(v1,v2) ;
       break;

va_end(argptr);
}
```

Comment: Проблемы: Некому вызвать Caller, прототип функции не универсален, это значит, что это колер не сможет вызвать все функции. Кроме того введения прототипа не решает проблему с вызовом некоторого класса функций, так как очевидно что я бы эту возможность свободно навешивать  на функцию (или вызывать ВСЕ функции через колер) .

Comment: Ну вы всерьез считаете после ваше модификации с флагом стало лучше ? Кроме того все еще не кому вызвать колер.

Comment: Что значит некому вызвать функцию `Caller` С это  компилируемый статически типизированный язык программирования поэтому вашу функцию должна вызвать как миниму функция `main`

Comment: Т.е. вы предлагаете мне все писать через Caller(AnyFunction, StupidFlag) ? Вопрос тогда в том нахер оно надо ? НЕт, я хочу получить функционал как у примера выше написал просто AnyFunction(Params);

Comment: Сделайте `flag` глобальной переменой тогда вызов будет таким `caller(void * fun)`

Comment: Да callerдолжен вызываться для всех функций проекта это очень много вызовов caller, а ведь еще и параметры предавать.